# ¿Como puedo medir la temperatura de un sensor de arduino en python?

Tags: python, c++, arduino

necesito medir los datos de un sensor de temperatura y pasarlos de arduino a python y despues regresarlos a arduino pra eso utilizo la funcion .readline() y .decode() ya logre enviar informacion de python a arduino el problema radica que cuando pyton recive los datos python no podia compararlos me decia no se pude compara un valor tipo byte con un flotante palabras mas palabras menos haci que decidi imprimirla para ver que se estava guradando pero no me imprimia nada puros saltos de linea, me que da claro que el error se encuentra en la forma de leer los datos python del arduino arduino pero nose cual es, podrian ayudarme porfa
le dejo el codigo de python y el de c++

codigo en python

```
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=115200, timeout = 1)
arduino.flushInput()
while True:
   temperatura = arduino.readline().decode()

   print(temperatura)

   time.sleep(0.1)

#arduino.close()
```

Codigo arduino

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#define sw_1 6//definimos el swith

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  

int lecturat = 0;//declaramos el pin del sensor temperatura
float temperatura = 0.0;// creamos una varable donde alamcenamos la temperatura
int tmenor;
int tmayor;


void setup()
{
  lcd.init();        
                          //configuracion del lcd y la velocidad
                      
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
}

void loop() 
{

if (Serial.available())//esto es para los mensajes en el monitor serial
{
   tmayor = Serial.parseFloat();
   delay(2000);
   Serial.flush();
   tmenor = Serial.parseFloat();
   lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  while (1)
  {
    
    temperatura = analogRead(lecturat);
    temperatura = (temperatura*(500.0/1023.0));
    Serial.println(temperatura);
    
     if (tmayor == 1)
  {
         lcd.setCursor(0,0);
         lcd.print("Temperatura Alta"); //imprimimos temperatura baja en el lcd
         lcd.setCursor(0,1);
         lcd.print(temperatura);
         delay(1000);
          
  }  

     else if (tmenor == 1)
     
  {
         lcd.setCursor(0,0);
         lcd.print("Temperatura Baja"); //imprimimos temperatura baja en el lcd
         lcd.setCursor(0,1);
         lcd.print(temperatura);
         delay(1000);
  }
      
     else if (digitalRead(sw_1)==1&&tmayor==0&&tmenor==0) // switch encendido
  {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Todo en orden");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print(temperatura); //imprimimos temperatura en el lcd
        delay(1000); 
    }     
       
     else if (digitalRead(sw_1)==0&&temperatura<tmayor&&temperatura>tmenor)//Switch 
     apagado
     { 
        lcd.clear();//limpiamos el lcd y segimos leyendo temperatura pero no imprimimos 
      en el lcd
       }
       delay(2000);
    }
    }
  }
```

El error no se encuentra en el circutio debido a que funcionaba perfectamnte antes de agregarle el codigo de python y no he movido nada.

Espero me puedan ayudar se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Si la pregunta estuviera en correcta en ortografía y redacción seguro que te la contesto. Así como está, mejor no.

Comment: `while (1){` Ahí ya tienes un problema mayúsculo en Arduino.

Comment: Conectaste el sensor al pin 0 del Arduino, que junto con el pin 1 se usan para la conexión Serial ...

Comment: `parseFloat()` puede terminar por *time-out*, sin devolver un valor.

Comment: Perdon por la ortografía tenía prisa. Una duda porque el While (1) es un error, una aclaración el sensor de temperatura esta conectado al pin analogico A0.

Comment: ¿Por qué `while(1)` es un error? Ay, hombre, como se nota que no has prestado atención.